# Is there a way to say a wheel split in half with a phrasal verb instead?

Tags: word-request, phrasal-verbs

Is there a way to say a wheel split in half with a phrasal verb instead?

> The wheel split in half after some rock tore a hole on it.

Is there a way to use for example "* off", but "came off" doesn't mean split in half, it just means the wheel came off it's axle. Maybe "split off", but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: One possible phrasal verb for the context is [*the wheel broke up.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+wheel+broke+up+and%22) But I can't see why you particularly want a phrasal verb. Just *the wheel broke* or *the wheel split* should be fine,

Comment: Possibly **the wheel came apart** but this simply means it broke into parts, not in half. The same is true of **the wheel shattered**.

Comment: Why do you want a phrasal verb in particular? Are you trying to remember one you've heard before?

Comment: BTW, do you mean the whole wheel or the tire (tyre)?